# Creating MLDataTable Using [MLDataTable.Rows.Element]

Tags: ios, swift, createml

I have an array of MLDataTable.Rows.Element and I want to construct a new MLDataTable with it. MLDataTable does not provide an initializers, which takes in the array etc. Any ideas how I can construct a new MLDataTable.